# Regular expression to find from the end of string

Tags: python, search, qregularexpression

I have a few strings, like:

```
address1 = 'Красноярский край, г Красноярск, ул Академика Вавилова, 2Д, кв. 311'
address2 = 'Москва г, ул Ольховская, 45 стр. 1, квартира 3'
address3 = 'Красноярский край, г Красноярск, ул Академика Вавилова, 2Д, квартира 311'
```

So I need to cut that piece of string, which start from **кв**.
I use regular expression and this my code:

```
import re

flat_template = r"кв(.*)$"

flat1 = re.search(flat_template, address1)
flat2 = re.search(flat_template, address2)
flat3 = re.search(flat_template, address3)

cut_flat1 = addresses[flat.start():flat.end()]
cut_flat2 = addresses[flat.start():flat.end()]
cut_flat3 = addresses[flat.start():flat.end()]

Output: 

cut_flat1 = 'кв. 311'
cut_flat2 = 'ква г, ул Ольховская, 45 стр. 1, квартира 3'
cut_flat3 = 'квартира 311'
```

But I want to get:

```
cut_flat1 = 'кв. 311'
cut_flat2 = 'квартира 3'
cut_flat3 = 'квартира 311'
```

All what I want to is search from end of string

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions usually are "greedy": they try to match as many characters as possible. That is what you see in your results.

You can make them non-greedy instead:

```
flat_template = r"кв(.*?)$"
```

Note the use of `.*?` for the non-greedy variant of `.*`. This will match the minum number of characters possible.

To make sure "кв" matches the beginning of a word, use a word boundary: `'\b'`:

```
flat_template = r"\bкв(.*?)$"
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your template for my code, but also added space before key word

Comment: @AidarDzhumagulov You'd need a word boundary instead: "кв. 311", or  "Москва г, ул Ольховская, 45 стр. 1,квартира 3" (due to a typo) would fail with a space, but a word boundary would solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve especially my problem. I have added space before ' кв'.
So my code

```
flat_template = r" кв(.*?)$"
```